# Get page number on click of page number datatable 1.9

Tags: datatable, datatables

I am using datatable version 1.9.x.

I want to get the page number if the user directly clicks on the page number, like 3 or 4.
I am able to get page number when he clicks next button using fnPagingInfo , but I am not able to get page number when he clicks the page directly.

This is my code :

```
$('#xyz').on('page dt', function () {
                    var info = bill_ov_np.selected.table.fnPagingInfo();
                    console.log(info);


            });
```

I can get the page number from above function, but only when user clicks next button, not when the page number is directly selected.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $(document).bind('click',"div.pagination li",function(evt){
                    var info = bill_ov_np.selected.table.fnPagingInfo();           
  });
```

This is the solution which I found and it is working for me.